# LocalDateTime.now() wrong hour

Tags: java, datetime

I'm using `LocalDateTime.now()` to get the date and time of system, but the time is with an hour in past.

If the system has 14:52, `now()` return 13:52.

OS of system is Windows 10.

Comment: is `TimeZone.getDefault()` equal to the timezone you expect it to be?

Comment: @Codeer `id = 'GMT+2'` and it should be `GMT+3`

Comment: -Duser.timezone="Australia/Sydney" (or whatever your locations is)

Comment: @CristianoBombazar where to set this? I don't get.

Comment: maybe you should try the [TimeZoneUpdater](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html) from the Oracle Download Page - could be that Java is not *aware*  of *summer time* (daylight saving time) for your location

Comment: @Codeer Make that `ZoneId.systemDefault` – which supplants the legacy `TimeZone` class.

Comment: Make sure your Windows time zone is correct and that it also respects summer time (DST) if such is used where you are. Usually Java picks up the OS time zone. Alternatively specify time zone when you start Java: `java -Duser.timezone=Asia/Amman (other args) YourApp`. Alternatively give time zone in `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jerusalem"))` (substitute your correct zone).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## `LocalDateTime` is wrong class

Never use `LocalDateTime` to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. Purposely lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, this type represents *potential* moments along the range of about 26-27 hours (range of time zones around the globe).

## Current moment

To get the current moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

To get the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by people in a particular region (a time zone), use `ZonedDateTime`.

I suspect your problem is that your expected time zone was not actually the current default zone when your code ran. In your code you failed to specify a time zone, and so the JVM’s current default time zone was silently applied. You could verify the current default by calling `ZoneId.systemDefault().toString()`.

Relying implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone is a bad practice in my opinion. Better to **always specify your desired/expected time zone** explicitly. Always pass the optional `ZoneId` argument.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ; // Or get the JVM’s current default time zone: ZoneId.systemDefault() 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.TimeZone.setDefault()`  is the method in java which is used to set the timeZone 
 in java. It takes `TimeZone` as input parameter. You can get an object of `TimeZone` by `TimeZone.getTimeZone("id");` There are different id for different time Zone. For example **id** for me is "**Asia/Calcutta**" so passing that will  return me the `TimeZone` of my region.

```
TimeZone tzone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
TimeZone.setDefault(tzone);
```

Above line will change my timezone to calcutta region.

Comment: Poor advice. This route should only be considered as a last resort in a desperate scenario. Setting the default time zone *immediately* affects all code in all threads of all apps running within the JVM. The wiser safer route is to ***never* rely on the current default time zone.** Always specify your desired/expected time zone as the optional argument in various method calls. And use only *java.time* classes, never `Date` or `Calendar`.